# Can't detect hard drive partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 alongside windows 7 but I can't figure out how to detect all the disk partitions I have already built in Windows. I have done a primary NTFS 30GB disk partition reserved to install ubuntu. But when I try to install Ubuntu from my pendrive it only detects a big 500GB partition. So I'd like to detect all of them so as to install Ubuntu in the place I want. I leave you some screenshots that might be useful.

[image: gparted]

[image: fixparts]

I'd really appreciate any comment or help!

Comment: please inform us, what size should be there for your windows and what size do you plan for Ubuntu. An installation simply "alongside" would be not the same like if you plan an installation with proper partition table. In the end you have more out of it for your fun with Ubuntu. ;o)